# como imprimo un arreglo a partir de una posición

Tags: java, array

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de un arreglo, hasta ahorita llevo como primer punto ordenar el arreglo de forma ascendente lo imprimo y todo bien.
Segundo punto tengo una variable `b`, la cual contiene `x` cantidad.
Tercer punto busco el valor de `b` en el arreglo, imprimo su valor y su posición si es que existe.

Mi duda es como puedo imprimir el arreglo con los valores menores a esa posición.

Les adjunto mi código:

```
public void calculaNumero(int b ){

     int[] num={3,2,5,6,1,8,4,7,9};

      for (int i = 0 ; i < num.length - 1 ; i++) {

        int min = i;

        //buscamos el menor número
        for (int j = i + 1 ; j < num.length ; j++) {
            if (num[j] < num[min]) {
                min = j;  
                //encontramos el menor número
            }
        }

        if (i != min) {
            //permutamos los valores
            int aux = num[i];
            num[i] = num[min];
            num[min] = aux;
        }
    }
  for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(i+") "+num[i]);
  }
     for (int i = 0 ; i < num.length ; i++) {
        if (num[i] == b) {
            int pos = i;

            if(pos<=b){
                System.out.println(" aqui ya se la posision de b y el valor    "+pos);

            }

        }

     }
}
```

Comment: Si la posición es la `4` por ejemplo, tu necesitas que imprima los valores del arreglo de la posición `0` a la `3`?

Comment: ¿Valores menores en posicion o en valor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para imprimir los valores de un vector simplemente tienes que ir recorriendolo.
Si lo que quieres es empezar en una posición POS e ir bajando simplemente puedes descontar:

```
for (int i = pos; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println("En la posición " + i + " el valor es " + vector[i])
}
```

Si por el contrario quieres los valores siguientes sería así:

```
 for (int i = pos; i < vector.lenth; i++) {
        System.out.println("En la posición " + i + " el valor es " + vector[i])
  }
```